# Best solution for a deployment plan/methodology that doesn't create hatred

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment

We're a small team of 3 developers and 1 application administrator that are all working on a single SharePoint installation for our Public Facing Website.

None of us have much experience with big time web application deployments, though we do have Perforce for version control.

We tend to write implementation plans into a Word document and it's casuing us problems. Our doc will have steps to run STSADM deployment CMD files, modify Web.CFG settings as needed and finally configure options in the GUI. Our problems always come down to environment hangups and general communication problems.

I wanted to get some input on how others are solving the same problems. We don't want anything too complex. We want something that functions better than the Word DOC, but doesn't take 2 weeks to learn to use.

Is there any software or web application out that that helps you plan a web application deployment?

Answer (score 4):

Automate this with a script. Store the script in your version control software. Run the script for deployment. No manual changes allowed - that way, your script must be fixed when you notice an error and you never ever forget to apply a manual fix. We don't manually patch binaries after assembly anymore either...

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Daren, that you want to start with a script. If that doesn't work, you'll want to work your way up the automation hierarchy towards something more complex. I'm guessing that my company's [uDeploy](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy/) is too much for your team, but somewhere between script and enterprise class deployment tool, there should be something that fits. Certainly at our end of thing, we have templates for .config files, easy file moves and drag and drop process designers. At the lower end, you might look at [octodeploy](http://octopusdeploy.com). I haven't had a chance to kick the tires, but it looks shiny, cheap and .Nety.

The non-negotiable part is automating. If you get on the automation path, good things will happen and you'll have a platform to build on. If you start caving to manual this and that, a year from now you'll have a larger and larger mess, more stressful deployments, and more Word documents than you want to deal with. At the extreme end, I've seen Word abandoned for multi-thousand line excel spreadsheets. Not fun.